# Modify the tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I have this theme but there's a problem:

I add the URL link of the photos at "Set a click-through link" but then when I visit my blog and I click at the photo, it doesn't direct me to the source URL. (it directs only If I'm browsing through the dashboard of tumblr and click on the photo, but not when going to my blog and clicking the photo - no). My blog is : colorinspirations.tumblr.com

For example this blog I checked (http://color-fantasia.tumblr.com/) has this functionality. Also when I click at the name of my blog (COLOR INSPIRATIONS) it doesn't do anything (for example to direct to the home page).

So please if you can help with:

1) "Set a click-through link" and the "content source URL" to be the same. (I use "Tumblr Post" extension for Firefox and it has the option for only "Set a click-through link". I need that when I enter the info on "Set a click-through link", the "content source URL" to be filled automatically with the URL of "Set a click-through link".)

2) When I click at the photo, it should direct me to the "source link" (it should be the same as the "set a click-through link")

3) When clicking the NAME of THE BLOG, it should direct to the Home Page.

I'd be very, VERY grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 2):

### Link site name to front page

To link your site heading with the front page, replace

```
<div id="nameBlog">
    {block:IfHeaderImageImage}
        <img id="imagetitle" src="{image:Header Image}">
    {/block:IfHeaderImageImage}

    {block:IfNotHeaderImageImage}
        <h1>{Title}</h1>
    {/block:IfNotHeaderImageImage}
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="nameBlog">
    {block:IfHeaderImageImage}
        <a href="/" rel="home"><img id="imagetitle" src="{image:Header Image}"></a>
    {/block:IfHeaderImageImage}

    {block:IfNotHeaderImageImage}
        <h1><a href="/" rel="home">{Title}</a></h1>
    {/block:IfNotHeaderImageImage}
</div>
```

### Link posts to source

See http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#content-sources for documentation of how to link content sources in themes.

The variable `{SourceURL}` gets replaced with the URL of your source. So you need to add `<a href="{SourceURL}">…</a>` around your content that should be linked. (Probably) wrap this content in `{block:ContentSource} … {/block:ContentSource}`, which means that it will only be processed, if a content source is present.

If you'd only like to link the source in the bottom of the post (if present, with source icon), you could [use this](http://staff.tumblr.com/post/1059624418/content-attribution):

```
{block:ContentSource}
    <a href="{SourceURL}">
        {lang:Source}:
        {block:SourceLogo}
            <img src="{BlackLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />

        {/block:SourceLogo}
        {block:NoSourceLogo}
            {SourceTitle}
        {/block:NoSourceLogo}
    </a>
{/block:ContentSource}
```

Comment: Hi unor, Thank you VERY much for the support and your time. Because I'm a complete noob in HTML/CSS I fear I would make any "damage" to the code when replacing it. Can you please make the changes to the theme provided for me? I'd appreciate it very much. (P.S. Yes it's OK to link the Content Source in the bottom of the post (the same way the site ffffound.com does). Using the Firefox extension, I can only add the Click-through link there. Is it possible that the Content Source to be the same as the Click-through link and to be placed at the bottom of the photo?)

Comment: @John: Here is your theme with a linked blog title: http://pastebin.com/fg8WAVhx – I've no time to dig into the source attribution, sorry. It might be easier to look for a different theme, because I think most should have this by default.